# how to place this wpf dockpanel properly

Tags: c#, wpf, dockpanel

I'm trying to make a WPF `DockPanel` which looks like the following picture

[image]

However I'm a beginner to WPF and I cannot get it correctly. Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
<WebBrowser DockPanel.Dock="top" Loaded="abc" Name="webBrowser0" />
<WebBrowser DockPanel.Dock="left" Loaded="abc" width="200" Name="webBrowser2" />
<WebBrowser DockPanel.Dock="Right" Loaded="abc"  Name="webBrowser2" />
<WebBrowser DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Loaded="abc" Name="webBrowser3" />
```